# Adding an Objective-C page in between JQtouch page

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cordova

I am making a PhoneGap Application. I am adding an Objective-C plugin(page) in between a JQtouch page. All pages have transitions from right to left, if returing back, left to right.

PROBLEM: When moving from Objective-C page(addressbook page) to JQtouch page(handled by JS) previous JQtouch page is coming in background and then new jqtouch page coming.

I want to remove this background.These transitions are needed.

**1.calling from JS to OBJ-C**

```
   PhoneGapViewController* cont = (PhoneGapViewController*)[ super appViewController ];
        addressbooVCObj.objectsForCharacters =objectsForCharacters;
        addressbooVCObj.arrayOfCharacters=arrayOfCharacters;
        addressbooVCObj.listOfItems=listOfItems;
        addressbooVCObj.copyListOfItems=copyListOfItems;
        /*presenting the addressbook page */
        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        // parent.view.window.layer is essential!
        [cont.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil ];
        [cont presentModalViewController:addressbooVCObj animated:NO];
        //[self CancelLikeButton];  
    }
    **2.BACK TO JS Page(working fine).**
    #pragma mark protocol method definition
    -(void)closeAddressbook:(NSString*)strToGoHomePage{
        NSLog(@"strToGoHomePage--->%@",strToGoHomePage);
        NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.addressBook._callback(\"%@\");", strToGoHomePage];
        DLGDebugLogInfo(@"jsCallback value is %@",jsCallback);
        [super writeJavascript:jsCallback];
    }
    **3.from OBJ-C page to new JS PAGE(problem area)**
    -(void)fromAddressBookToNewPage:(int)indexnumber{
        NSLog(@"indexnumber--->%d",indexnumber);
        NSString* jsCallback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.plugins.addressBook._dateSelected(\"%@%d\");",@"cntct_",indexnumber];
    DLGDebugLogInfo(@"jsCallback value is %@",jsCallback);
    [super writeJavascript:jsCallback];
    }
```

after returning back from this function to JS.JS opening a new JS page with animation from right to left (OBJ-c page moving from right tpo left) but gap is coming in between thewre two page(that previous page in background is coming).

Is it possible to use present modal from Objective-C page to js DIV?